# I can't switch graphic card on a Intel/AMD hybrid graphics laptop

Tags: 16.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I have two graphic cards: **Intel** (integrated) and **AMD/Radeon** (dedicated GPU) with `radeon` drivers.

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom        
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:277 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:278 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0040000-d005ffff
```

I'm not able to tell if my OS has ever used the GPU in 2 years. **I don't know how to switch or rather, I don't seem to be able to switch, graphic card.**

I might have done things in the past that I can't recall, and I don't know whether I'm stuck in some strange status. All I know is that I've never been able to use the GPU.

---

#### Some info

I think that my system is generally using the integrated card (`name=Intel`):

```
~$ xrandr --listproviders

Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

(The above command should also output a third line "Provider 1", right? I don't know why it doesn't!)

I have this line in GRUB: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1"` and I have `CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y` in  every `/boot/config-*`. So according to [the wiki on Hybrid Graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) I should be able to use a switcheroo.

However, I can't seem to be able to switch anything: (the following run as root)

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0

# echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

Also, setting `DRI_PRIME` doesn't do anything:

```
~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
~$ DRI_PRIME=1 xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
~$ DRI_PRIME=0 xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

---

#### To summarize

How can I use my GPU and how can I check that I'm using my GPU?